# Adding thousand separator to extracted website data

Tags: php, html, xpath, web-scraping, domdocument

I have a code that retrieve the integer values and then totalling them. However, when I attempt to add thousand separator to the extracted value, it will not totalled correctly.

This is the code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://www.alibaba.com/Products');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $finder->query('//h4[@class="sub-title"]');

$total_A = 0;
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $sub_no =  (int) preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', trim(explode("\n", trim($node->nodeValue))[2]))  . '<br/>';
    $total_A += $sub_no;
    echo $sub_no;
    $convert = number_format( $total_A , 0 , '.' , ',' );
}

    echo "Total: $convert";
?>
```

I tried :

```
  $sub_no =  number_format(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', trim(explode("\n", trim($node->nodeValue))[2])), 0 , '.' , ',' )  . '<br/>';
```

and it works for the extracted value but the total will be messed up. How can I correct this? Thanks!

EDIT: I managed to get the correct output for the total: 407,418,309 but I also want the 
$sub_no to have thousand seperator too when I echo it(not just the total). But when I do it, the total will be displayed wrongly.
Output should be like this:
397,893,1  #notice the separator?
184,471,0
729,391,9
etc...
Total: 407,418,309

Comment: Generally you'll want to format the number after all calculations are complete. The `number_format()` is meant for display purposes, as a way to make your final output look how you want it.

Comment: what's the correct output anyway? `407,418,309`? seems working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just sum total all of the variables first, then just format them in the end for viewing purposes. The simple logic here is that separate the arithmetic first, then format them after the arithmetic so that no conflict will go into that.

```
$total_A = 0;
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $sub_no =  (int) preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', trim(explode("\n", trim($node->nodeValue))[2]));
    $total_A += $sub_no;
    echo number_format($sub_no, 0 , '.' , ',' ) . '<br/>';
}

echo "Total: ".number_format($total_A, 0 , '.' , ',' );
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not echo the final output as `number_format()`?

```
echo "Total: ".number_format($convert, 0 , '.' , ',' );
```

OR rather:

```
$total_A = 0;
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $sub_no =  (int) preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', trim(explode("\n", trim($node->nodeValue))[2]))  . '<br/>';
    $total_A += $sub_no;
    echo $sub_no;
}

    echo "Total: ".number_format($total_A, 0 , '.' , ',' );
```